# Is there any reasonable argument against immediately validating a new customer's email address?

Tags: validation, identity-theft

Would it not be useful for account providers that allow online/phone signup/ordering to immediately verify the email address supplied to them?

I was forced to ponder this recently when I became the apparent victim of identity theft.  Someone used my name and email address when opening an account with a US-based Internet service provider and placed an order for service at a US mainland street address.  I am neither a US citizen nor live in the US, and do not have any reason to need or want an Internet service there.

I became aware of it when I received two emails; first an "Order Confirmation" followed by a shipping advice for equipment being sent to the street address in question.  I contacted the company via their web "chat" but was advised that my only recourse for cancelling/closing the account was to submit to them via postal mail a compendium of supporting evidence to prove my identity including a comprehensive collection of personal ID (photocopy of driver's licence, proof of address, etc.).  I was dumbfounded to learn that the account/order was placed against my name and email address without any validation of the email address being performed.  It seems to me that if this one simple procedure had been performed then the entire apparent scam could have been thwarted and the company would have avoided aiding the perpetrator and a great deal of personal distress and effort for me could have been averted.

Am I overlooking anything?  Is there a reason why validating a new customer's email address prior to activating a new account and proceeding with order processing isn't a practicable precaution?  I realise that there are circumstances in which it may not be effective, but it would at least have been useful in this scenario and saved a great deal of consternation and wasted time.

Full disclosure: about a week later, after submitting ID theft reports to local and US authorities, and visiting my bank to take measures to ensure my bank accounts would be protected, I spoke with a member of this company's "Security Team" and learned that in this case it appears to have been a genuine mistake.  The customer's name and email address differed to mine by a single letter which was phonetically similar - either the customer had mis-typed their information or had been mis-heard by a phone operator.  The mistaken identity had been resolved on the account - but I had not been informed despite having lodged two complaints with their online customer support.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, they probably don't want to bother people with unnecessary steps. Why would you bother asking them to validate their email address after a lengthy sign-up process with lots of fields already? You want customers to have a good experience and finish signing up for the service without hurdles, who cares if their email address is valid. Worst case you send them a letter, which will have to arrive because the service (in this case) is delivered to a home address. If it's not a valid home address, then it would also be fine to cut the service as there can be no service. The most important detail to the ISP will be the payment details, not whether they're accidentally sending the order confirmation to another email address.

I am sorry you had to deal with this, but I'm not sure there is a definitive answer to this question. Many reasons can be thought of, the most obvious one being usability.

Comment: You have covered why they likely don't _want_ to do it (why should it be classed "unnecessary"?) but that doesn't address my question:  Is there any reason why it wouldn't be (sufficiently) useful and/or practicable to do the validation?  My experience clearly demonstrates how it can be useful for all parties.  The failure cases I can think of are where the email account is compromised anyway, or where the unintended recipient of the validation request dishonestly or mistakenly affirms the validation request.  While it clearly can't offer a guarantee, neither does most personal ID validation.

Comment: @ovirt Are you sure you're not just looking for confirmation of what you already think must be the truth without considering the viewpoint of the ISP and their customers?

Comment: Are you suggesting that the usability/Customer Experience factor renders an email validation step not practicable and/or not useful?

Comment: @ovirt Of course customer experience plays a role in every digital environment, just like security does. Why do you think online banking exists in the first place? We could also just *go to the bank* to do transactions. It's not because online banking on user-controlled devices is more secure than doing it in person... Anyway, it still sounds like you want me to reply "of course we can't ignore security for usability" (while the truth is, as usual, in the middle; life isn't black or white). Are you sure you're not just looking for confirmation of what you already think must be the case?